# Huawei Scene Kit, 3D model does not display after loading finishes

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, gltf, 3d-modelling, huawei-developers

I'm using the Huawei Scene Kit to load a 3D model (glTF format), and after I finish loading, the model does not display in-app. I checked the developer documentation and glTF is supposed to be a supported format. Is there something not mentioned in the documentation I'm supposed to do in order to load my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether your 3D materials are loaded from the local assets directory or not. ( A must in SDK version: com.huawei.scenekit:sdk:5.0.2.302)

Also check whether 3D materials are correct. If the materials have some problems, they will be abnormally displayed or even fail to be displayed.

> To check 3D materials, you could use [glTF Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)

For glTF materials, you still need to do the following:

- Check whether the URI in images is correct, and whether the material
  type is  supported by Scene Kit of the version you are using.
- Check whether mimeType of bufferView in images is supported by Scene
  Kit of the version you are using.

> Scene Kit of current version 5.0.2.302 is unable to load or display light,
> camera, or animations of glTF materials.

Answer (score 1):

There are requirements for supported devices and also supported regions, please go through the below link to confirm if your device and region is supported.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/restrictions-0000001050161552-V5

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/restrictions-0000001050161552-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001052360202__section134581494535

Answer (score 0):

Scene Kit [Materials to be rendered](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/restrictions-0000001050161552#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001052360202__section19152121114545?ha_source=hms1) includes glTF and glb. So glTF files should work in Scene Kit, and according to your description, this problem might be caused by **missing texture or bin files** which are linked to the .gltf file. Please try copying the gltf file you want to load along with its bin and texture files, then rerun the App. If the 3D model still not display, please provide logs for error analysis and locating.